# Time shift in updating JavaFX GUI with actual position from Arduino/Grbl

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, terminal

I want to show the actual position of a machine controlled with an arduino and installed grbl in JavaFX. Therefore I have a timer in the FXML Controller to send a command (?) every 200 milliseconds via the serial terminal to the arduino/grbl.

**FXML Controller**

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask updatePos = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        grblSender.sendLine("?");
    }
};
timer.schedule(updatePos, 200, 200);
```

Then I have a Listener class to catch the incoming responds from the serial terminal to process them.

**GrblListener**

```
class GrblListener implements SerialPortEventListener {

    @Override
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {

        if(event.isRXCHAR() && event.getEventValue() > 0){

            try {
                String input = GrblSender.serialPort.readString();
                System.out.println(input.trim());

                if(input.startsWith("<Idle")) 
                Main.controller.updateCurrentPosition(input.trim());
            }
                catch (SerialPortException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the FXML controller I want to update textFields for x,y and z position with the method updateCurrentPosition.

**FXML Controller**

```
public void updateCurrentPosition(String position){
    try{
        String[] pos = position.split(":");
        try{
            String mPos = pos[1];
            try{
                String[] mPosSplit = mPos.split(",");

                textFieldPositionX.setText(mPosSplit[0]);
                textFieldPositionY.setText(mPosSplit[1]);
                textFieldPositionZ.setText(mPosSplit[2]);
            }catch(Exception e){}               
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }catch(Exception e){}
}
```

The problem is, that the GUI is only updated after a command is finished.
E.g. I send the command: G0 X10
Then the GUI is showing the correct position after the command (X:10, Y:0, Z:0), but not the changing position while the processing of the command.

Output of the console is correct and NOT time shifted:

```
<Run,MPos:0.008,0.000,0.000,WPos:0.008,0.000,0.000>
ok
<Run,MPos:0.292,0.000,0.000,WPos:0.292,0.000,0.000>
ok
<Run,MPos:0.976,0.000,0.000,WPos:0.976,0.000,0.000>
ok
<Run,MPos:2.068,0.000,0.000,WPos:2.068,0.000,0.000>
ok
<Run,MPos:3.380,0.000,0.000,WPos:3.380,0.000,0.000>
ok
<Run,MPos:4.332,0.000,0.000,WPos:4.332,0.000,0.000>
ok
<Run,MPos:4.876,0.000,0.000,WPos:4.876,0.000,0.000>
ok
<Idle,MPos:5.000,0.000,0.000,WPos:5.000,0.000,0.000>
ok
<Idle,MPos:5.000,0.000,0.000,WPos:5.000,0.000,0.000>
ok
```

What's the mistake? Should I use threads and when so how?

Comment: I found the mistake: if(input.startsWith("<Idle") || input.startsWith("<Run"))